# Photoshop CEP: JSX Object to JS

Tags: extendscript

I'm running into an issue with sending data from JSX to JS using evalScript in Photoshop.

In the following example I attempt to send the document width, height and ruler units within an object, docInfo, back to my CEP Panel JS.

The issue is that when I parse the object it shows the three properties all as objects, when I believe they should all be strings.

**JS**:

```
    function psdInfo() {
        csInterface.evalScript("getDocInfo()", function(res) {
            if (EvalScript_ErrMessage == res) {
                console.error('EvalScript_ErrMessage and res is' + typeof res + ' res is ' + res);
            }
            else {
                var o = JSON.parse(res);
                var str = "Object received from JSX:\n";
                for (var prop in o) {
                    str += prop + " [" + typeof o[prop] +" ]: " + o[prop] + ".\n"; 
                }
                console.log(str);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

**JSX**:

```
function getDocInfo()
{
    var doc = app.activeDocument,
        docWidth = doc.width,
        docHeight = doc.height,
        originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnit;


    var docInfo = {
        width: docWidth,
        height: docHeight,
        originalRulerUnits: originalRulerUnits
    };
    return JSON.stringify(docInfo);
}
```

**What I'd expect**:

```
Object received from JSX:
width [string ]: '1920 px'.
height [string ]: '1920 px'.
originalRulerUnits [string ]: 'UNITS.PIXELS'.
```

**What I get**:

```
Object received from JSX:
width [object ]: [object Object].
height [object ]: [object Object].
originalRulerUnits [object ]: [object Object].
```

My question is - am I doing something wrong? Are these in fact objects?

If they are, how do I get the info I'm after? How do I parse/convert the object on the JSX side to string or should I do that on the JS side?

An example of how-to would be really helpful. I'm trying to learn Adobe CEP panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are specific to Photoshop objects defined by ExtendScript: height and width are `UnitValues` (they carry both a value and a unit) and rulerUnits are `Units`, JSON can't correctly pass them as objects from JSX to JS. So before passing `docInfo` you need to make sure you've converted them to strings using `.toString()` method:

```
function getDocInfo()
{
    var doc = app.activeDocument,
        docWidth = doc.width.toString(),
        docHeight = doc.height.toString(),
        originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits.toString();

    var docInfo = {
        width: docWidth,
        height: docHeight,
        originalRulerUnits: originalRulerUnits
    };
    return JSON.stringify(docInfo);
}
```

result:

```
{"width":"1024 px","height":"1024 px","originalRulerUnits":"Units.PIXELS"}
```

You can read more about specific object in [JavaScript Tools Guide pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf): there're `File`, `Folder`, `SolidColor` and others.